# Do string decryption require guid and iv (initialization vector)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am doing string encryption like below using the guid and storing the cipherout.ciphertext value but not storing the cipherout.iv value.
But when decrypting , why cant i just pass the key , instead of passing both key and cipherout.iv values. Because it is asking for both values while decrypting it. Do i need to store both key and cipherout.iv values for decrypting?
Please advice

FIRSTFILE.js :

````
var guid = "4ab23a136dc347d";
var inputString = "sometext";

// Create the key
var key = crypto.createSecretKey({guid:guid, encoding:encode.Encoding.UTF_8});

// Encrypt
var cipher = crypto.createCipher({algorithm: crypto.EncryptionAlg.AES, key: key});
cipher.update({input: inputString, inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8});
var cipherout = cipher.final({outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.HEX});```
````

SECONDFILE.JS

````
// Decrypt
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher({algorithm: crypto.EncryptionAlg.AES, key: key, iv:cipherout.iv}); //HERE 
decipher.update({input: cipherout.ciphertext, inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.HEX});
var decipherout = decipher.final({outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to store both. Without initial vector it's not possible to decrypt message even with password. The idea is: password can be same for all messages, but IV is created when it was encrypted and it's different always.
IV can be encrypted with 4096 RSA, but all message cab be too long for RSA and you encryp it with AES.
AES is not good from security perspective, so we need use password AND one-time-key - initial vector.